# Setting a fixed width for contents of a RadComboBox

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik

In XAML I have a Telerik `RadComboBox` that is binding to some values and shows themes in the drop down. The problem is the text of some of these items are too long which will cause the drop down list to resize on the fly to show the full content of that item and when we pass it again it resizes back to its original size.

What I need to do is to find out how can I:

1. stop it from resizing its drop down content automatically when the item text is too long.
2. add a horizontal scroll bar so users can still scroll horizontally and see the content of the long item.

Comment: You will come to loathe telerik SL controls, in a lot of cases they're sloppy templates, leaky, and can quickly become a big pain in the *** (at least that's been my experience in SL4.) You're going to have to tear through the Control Templates, I would suggest using Blend. However you're going to find their documentation somewhat lacking in this regard and an answer to your question would end up being long and broad. Start by Right clicking -> Edit Template, and work your way through from there to find the right place to edit.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisW -- please note also, it's impossible to provide a complete answer unless you at least specify the name of the Telerik "drop down" control.

Comment: @McGarnagle it is a radComboBox

Comment: They have implemented exactly what I do NOT want: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/radcombobox-auto-width.aspx  I need the reverse. Don't auto-change the width based on the item text length and show a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @DevWannaBe that link is to an ASP Ajax solution. You'll want info for the SL controls. What you're wanting can be done, you'll just have to dig around for the template to edit where you can specify your fixed width and wrap the `ContentPresenter` in a `ScrollViewer`

Comment: In the control template of combo box there should be a scroll viewer, in the Popup - if not, surround the `ItemsPresenter` with one. Set scroll viewer's `Width="yourDesiredWidth"` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`.